# C++ double pointer array to float conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

What is a correct way to convert double to float in c++. Is the conversion implicit?

**Question 1:** Consider `double d = 5.0;` and `float f;`

Which one is correct?

- `f = d;`
- `f = (float)d;`
- `f = static_cast<float>(d);`

**Question 2:** Now consider we have

```
char *buffer = readAllBuffer(); 
double *d = (double*)(buffer + offset);
float f;
```

Which one is now correct?

- `f = d[0];`
- `f = (float)d[0];`
- `f = static_cast<float>(d[0]);`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of them are really correct considering a `double` can store more than a `float` can so can you loose precision or the value completely

Comment: The two questions are really the same. You start with a `double` value in either case and want to convert to a `float` value. In other words, how you obtain the `double` is independent of converting it to `float`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Loosing precision is not problem here. which one gives me the closest number? Since I have to convert double to float?

Comment: @Mogi - they all will give you the same resulting `f` value.

Comment: @chris I thought the buffer size may have an influence on the value

Comment: did you perform a google search?! here is the answer http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/40303/ and  http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/64482/

Comment: @MohammadSalehDehghanpour salam, Yep I did. But I could not found what i meant. tnx anyway

Comment: Your question 2 is illformed as you try to assign a `const double*` to a `double*`.

Comment: @sebrockm: Not necessarily; only if the original array is read-only and the program attempts to modify data pointed at by `d`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I meant that it won't compile. He would have to cast away the `const`. Or, of course, directly cast it to non-const `double*`.

Comment: @Aconcagua sry, I think you mixed smth up. You are copying a `const double` to a `double`. But the OP is (was, (s)he corrected it meanwhile) copying a `const double*` to a `double*` which is precisely what `const_cast` is good for. C++ only allows you to do that if you explicitly cast the const away. It does not work implicitly for the reason you stated correctly. Try it out.

Comment: @sebrockm Ah, sorry, my fault. needed to peek back into history - and found exactly my sample for invalid code in slightly different form... Don't even know any more how I came from that to assuming you meant assigning const to non-const by value... Maybe should go to bed - but it's only 1/2 5 pm here???.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They all boil down to the same thing, and the use of arrays is a red herring. You can indeed write

```
float f = d;
```

Some folk argue that a `static_cast` makes code more readable as it sticks out so clearly. It can also defeat warnings that some compilers might issue if a less long-winded form is used.

Naturally of course since a `double` is a superset of `float`, you might lose precision. Finally, note that for

```
float f1 = whatever;
double d1 = f1;
float f2 = d1;
```

, the C++ standard insists that `f1` and `f2` must be the same value.

Comment: static_cast helps to wipe out warning message about truncating from double to float. I belive this is the main reason for using it, not readability

Comment: @Jeka: Indeed you're correct. I have all such warnings explicitly suppressed in all my builds.

Answer (score 0):

You do have one major issue.  This is not allowed:

```
double *d = (double*)(buffer + offset);
```

It violates strict aliasing and quite possibly alignment requirements.  Instead you need to use `memcpy`:

```
double d;
memcpy(&d, buffer + offset, sizeof d);
float f = d;
```

Either of the cast alternative can be substituted for the last line, the important change is from dereferencing an pointer with incorrect type and alignment to making a bytewise copy.

Comment: It depends of the real type at `buffer + offset` BTW. (can be a `double*` casted to `char*` and restore back to `double*`) (Name of the function suggest it is not the case though).